# Thread was being aborted error while deleting files from file system

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, iis, io

I get the error "Thread was being aborted" while trying to delete some temporary files from a certain directory.  I think this problem is specific to the code below, because application pool is not recycled while the code is running (as far as I observed).
The piece of code below runs successfully if it takes 3-5 seconds. But when the count of files are bigger, I get the error after 12 or 15 seconds.
I assume its not a global timeout etc because there are other threads which take much more time than this one, and still not get aborted. 
Can it be related to I/O operation?
This is the piece of code:

```
DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
IEnumerable<string> directories = Directory.EnumerateDirectories(_pathOfTempFiles);
directories= directories.Concat(new[] { _pathOfTempFiles }); 
foreach (string dirPath in directories)
{

    DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(dirPath);
    foreach (FileInfo fi in di.EnumerateFiles())
    {
        if (now.Subtract(fi.CreationTime).TotalHours >= 2 && !fi.Name.ToLower().Contains("web.config") && !fi.Name.ToLower().Contains("web.confıg"))
        {                        
            try
            {
                fi.Delete();                            
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {                                                        
                _messages.Add("Exception : " + ex.Message + " ~ " + fi.Name);

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you running this in a new thread?

Comment: Post the complete error message you're getting. Rather than `ex.Message`, output `ex.ToString()`.

Comment: @JimMischelat This is the stack trace: 

Microsoft.Win32.Win32Native.DeleteFile(String path) at System.IO.FileInfo.Delete() 
at ASW_Is.BackGround.DeleteTempData.PRMTakFFbrQkpFBawoM(Object ) 
at ASW_Is.BackGround.DeleteTempData.deleteTempFiles()

deleteTempFiles is where my code is running

Answer (score 0):

A wild guess. Not sure it's not getting recycled... Are you [deleting the files](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/johan/archive/2007/05/16/common-reasons-why-your-application-pool-may-unexpectedly-recycle.aspx) which trigger App Pool recycling by design? Asking 'cause this can lead to aborted threads... In 2-3 seconds you might get away with that -- the app will be relaunched anyway, but you won't see a thread abort. Massive/lengthy deletions in the wrong places can trigger series of recycles, making the exceptions more likely.

Also: there are numerous settings (like inactivity timeout, etc), which might put your app out of the game unexpectedly. Make sure you don't hit that.